# Creating 1D Barcode using the Google Chart API /ZXING library

Tags: php, zxing, google-visualization

I am trying to create 1D barcodes using PHP.I have been able to create the 2 D Qr code using the google chart api like this:

```
 $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_REQUEST['content']);
$content       = $string;//$_REQUEST['content'];
$correction    = strtoupper($_REQUEST['correction']);
$encoding      = $_REQUEST['encoding'];

//form google chart api link
$rootUrl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=$size&chl=$content&choe=$encoding&chld=$correction";

//print out the image
echo '<img src="'.$rootUrl.'">';
```

This code simply generates the QR code.But i need barcode.What will i need to change in parameters to display it as 1D barcode??? Please note I am using PHP language and decoding data using Zxing library.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The API you're using is deprecated(https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/). And as far as I see, Google does not offer a 1D barcode generator API.

I suggest you stop using this API and download a class which can generate barcodes. ZF example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub InsertQR()
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
Dim Size: Size = 250 'dalam Pixels
Dim QR, Name, val

Dim Invalid: Invalid = "\/:*?" & """" & "<>|"
For Each val In Selection
    Name = val.Value
    Barcode = val.Value
    For intChar = 1 To Len(Name)
        If InStr(Invalid, LCase(Mid(Name, intChar, 1))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "The file: " & vbCrLf & """" & Name & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " is invalid!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    QR = "https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=" & Barcode & "&code=Code128&dpi=96&dataseparator=" & Size & "x" & Size & "&cht=qr&chl=" & Name
    xHttp.Open "GET", QR, False
    xHttp.Send
    With bStrm
        .Type = 1 '//binary
        .Open
        .write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Name & ".png", 2 '//overwrite
        .Close
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: I created this which allows me to generate barcodes from data in Excel.